# How to merge two or more Counters into a single dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two Counter collections C1 and C2, they have similar data set but different counts (think C1 and C2 as number of apples and oranges a group of people have).

I want to merge these two collections into one dict that looks like

```
{
Person1: [1, 2],
Person2: [5, 1],
...
}
```

I haven't decided what data structure to store the merged counts (perhaps list) in order to easily write them to a csv file with # of apples and oranges being separate columns. There are a lot of tricks I am not aware of in python collections, I am looking for minimal code size. Thanks.

EDIT: From the answers below, I felt that my question is not as clear as I thought, let me elaborate on what exactly what I am looking for:
Let me have two Counter collections c1 and c2:

```
c1 = [
  ('orange', 10),
  ('apple', 20)
]

c2 = [
  ('orange', 15),
  ('apple', 30)
]
```

I want to merge these two collections into a single dict such that it looks like:

```
merged = {
  'orange': [10, 15],
  'apple': [20, 30]
}
```

Or other data structure that can be easily converted and output to csv format.

Comment: Are they guaranteed to have the same keys?

Comment: @LevLevitsky Yes, guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module to store the merged result then you use [`chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module. What `chain` is doing here is that it makes an iterator that returns elements from each of your "counter" and let you avoid writing a nested loop.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> c1 = [
...   ('orange', 10),
...   ('apple', 20)
... ]
>>> c2 = [
...   ('orange', 15),
...   ('apple', 30)
... ]
>>> merged = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in chain(c1, c2):
...     merged[item[0]].append(item[1])
... 
>>> merged
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'apple': [20, 30], 'orange': [10, 15]})
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

c1 = Counter('jdahfajksdasdhflajkdhflajh')
c2 = Counter('jahdflkjhdazzfldjhfadkhfs')


df = pd.DataFrame({'apples': c1, 'oranges': c2})
df.to_csv('apples_and_oranges.csv')
```

This works also if the keys of the counters are not all the same. There will be NaNs where the key only appeared in the other counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Counter.update()` function if you start form a counter collection as you specified. I added the item `banana` as well, which is only in one counter collection. Be aware that `update` used on a `Counter` adds the values to the key. This is in contrast to `update` used on a `dict` where the value is replaced (!) by the update (check the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update).

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

c1 = [('orange', 10),('apple', 20)]
c2 = [('orange', 15),('apple', 30),('banana',5)]
c = Counter()
for i in c1: c.update({i[0]:i[1]})
for i in c2: c.update({i[0]:i[1]})
```

However, if you start form a list of values you can construct a `Counter` for each list and add the counters

```
c1 = Counter(['orange'] * 10 + ['apple'] * 20)
c2 = Counter(['orange'] * 15 + ['apple'] * 30 + ['banana']* 5)
c = c1 + c2
```

Now we can write the counter to a csv file

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index', columns=['count'])
df.to_csv('counts.csv')
```

Yet another way is to convert the counter collection to `dicts` and form there to `Counters`, since you are looking for a small code size

```
c1 = Counter(dict([('orange', 10),('apple', 20)]))
c2 = Counter(dict([('orange', 15),('apple', 30),('banana',5)]))
c = c1 + c2
```